# Having issue with click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, click, submit

```
$('#delete').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var result = true;
    if($('.checkbox:checked').length < 1) {
        $.notifyBar({
            cls: "error",
            html: 'At least 1 checkbox must be checked.',
            delay: 5000
        });
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
});
```

the problem is button doesn't submit form if all goes well
Is there any wrong?

Comment: Please link to a complete JSFiddle reproducing the problem.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. "Indenting your code" and "producing code that works" are in direct correlation. *(@JamWaffles did it for you this time, please do it yourself next time)*

Comment: remove e.preventDefault() and it will submit your form, if false it will just show notifyBar

Comment: Tried removing `e.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: @Codemonkey I sort of cheated a bit and used [this](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to format the JS. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `e.preventDefault()` is preventing the default action of the button which is to submit the form.  You need to only call that when you don't want a submit to occur.

```
$('#delete').click( function(e) {
  if($('.checkbox:checked').length<1){
    $.notifyBar({
      cls: "error",
      html: 'At least 1 checkbox must be checked.',
      delay: 5000
    });

    // Invalid, stop the submit
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
$('#delete').click(function (e) {
    var result = true;

    if($('.checkbox:checked').length < 1) {
        $.notifyBar({
            cls: "error",
            html: 'At least 1 checkbox must be checked.',
            delay: 5000
        });
        result = false;
    }

    if(!result) e.preventDefault();
});
```

The call to `e.preventDefault();` will prevent the submit button from submitting no matter what you return from the function. In my edit the default action is only prevented if result is false.

Answer (score 0):

Using `e.preventDefault();` will stop the form from submitting, even if `true` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this in the onsubmit handler instead of the click handler. Also, ensure the button that you want them to click is of type submit:

```
 function doSubmit()
 {
    var result = true;

    if($('.checkbox:checked').length < 1) {
        $.notifyBar({
            cls: "error",
            html: 'At least 1 checkbox must be checked.',
            delay: 5000
        });
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
  }


 <form onsubmit="return doSubmit()">

     Checkboxes....

     <input type="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```